# c# - Cannot convert from List<DateTime?> to List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I am trying to create an attribute in a list that takes different types. This is my class:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> data { get; set; }

    public ChartData()
    {
    }

    public ChartData(string id, List<DateTime?> data)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

    public ChartData(string id, List<float?> data)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ChartData(string id, List<int?> data)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
```

In the code I use the `data` list to store `DateTime?`, `float?` or `int?` data. What do I do to be able to store these different types in one class attribute?

I am getting the error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>'
```

Comment: If you really wanna do this you should take `object` instead of `dynamic`. But I would recommend not doing this because it's pain in the ass when you want to get the values because you have to check which type of value you have.

Comment: I get the same error with `object`. What can I use instead of a `List<T>`?

Comment: What type of data is `context.system_state` respectively the property `time_stamp`?

Comment: I think the problem is your T parameters are nullable

Comment: @MatthewEvans I tried having them non-nullable and I still get the same error.

Comment: What is the advantage of putting it all in one list? Why don't you keep seperate lists inside the class? How do you plan to use the combined list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using Generics if you know the type prior to instantiation

```
public class ChartData
{
   public string id { get; set; }
}

public class ChartData<T> : ChartData
{
    public List<T> data { get; set; }

    public ChartData()
    {
    }

    public ChartData(string id, List<T> data)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ChartData<int> intData = new ChartData<int>("ID1", new List<int>());
ChartData<DateTime> dateData = new ChartData<DateTime>("ID1", new List<DateTime>());
ChartData<float> floatData = new ChartData<float>("ID1", new List<float>());



List<ChartData> list = new List<ChartData>() {
    intData,
    dateData,
    floatData
};
```

Comment: And how do the setup the list where he want#s to store the `ChartData<T> `instances? He would need a base class or an interface as wel.

Comment: Yes, this works. I have done that, but I want to also create a `List<ChartData>` and I don't know what type to use there, since I want this list to contain all three `ChartData` types.

Comment: If you need to store all chart date in a single collection, regardless of the data type of "data", then you need a base class ChartData that has no generic parameters. @MightyBadaboom

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think change below should work:
**FROM**

```
 public List<dynamic> data { get; set; }
```

**TO**

```
 public dynamic data { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you do this you lose the `List<T>` members, so you would not even know it is a list.

Answer (score 2):

If it suits your case you can use [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) collection like this:

```
IReadOnlyList<dynamic> data;
data = new List<string>();
```

But it works with reference types only.

If you don't care what type is it you can use List for your data.

For more convenient access you can use something like this:

```
private IList data;
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Data { get { return data.OfType<dynamic>(); } }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may use LINQ to convert list items' type:

```
public ChartData(string id, List<DateTime?> data)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
}
```

Important note: in this case you're creating a duplicate of the list and changes in the caller's instance of the list won't be reflected in the `ChartData`'s instance (which is probably even better, though.)